# Comprobar campos llenos jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, entrada

estoy intentando hacer un comprobación de 2 input text y cuando se ejecuta el keyup, aunque solo este relleno el input name, entra por el else y no se cumple el IF.

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#formulario input").keyup(function() {

      $NombreText = $("#name").val();
      $ApellidosText= $("#surname").val();

      if( $NombreText.length<=0 && $ApellidosText.length<= 0){

        console.log("vacio")
      }
      else{
        console.log("lleno")
      } 
   });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formulario" action="">

    <label for="">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">

    <label for="">Apellidos</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname">

    <button>ENVIAR</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Por que no utilizas los atributos de html, por ejemplo: **required**,  <input type="text" id="surname" required>

Comment: quiero comprobar que ambos campos están llenos, para que en este caso ejecutar una cambio de CSS y saber porque no se esta cumpliendo el if. No se si con required puedo hacerlo también

Comment: Daniel la condición es si ambos campos están vacíos dime "vacío", tendría que ser un "|| o OR", es decir, si uno de ellos o ambos están vacíos.

Comment: Carmen, ya he visto el problema con otro usuario, pero muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo cambie la logia del **if** cambie el `&&` por el `||`:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#formulario input").keyup(function() {

      $NombreText = $("#name").val();
      $ApellidosText= $("#surname").val();

      if( $NombreText.length<=0 || $ApellidosText.length<= 0){

        console.log("vacio")
      }
      else{
        console.log("lleno")
      } 
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" action="">

    <label for="">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">

    <label for="">Apellidos</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname">

    <button>ENVIAR</button>

</form>
```

Espero sea la respuesta a tu problema.

Comment: Perfecto, funciona como yo quería, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Genial, si puedes colocar mi respuesta como correcta te agradecería mucho. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías escribirlo de una manera más corta así:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#formulario input").keyup(function() {
        console.log( !$("#name").val() && !$("#surname").val() ? 'vacio' : 'lleno');
   });
});
```